# icon.rc and icon.ic error in qt :-1: error: error: icon.rc: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, icons

I'm getting the following errors when trying to compile

:-1: error: error: icon.rc: No such file or directory
:-1: error: fatal error: no input files

In my icon.rc file:
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "icon.ico"

The code compiles fine on other computers, just when trying to compile on my computer I get this error

Comment: is it in the same path as your source code?

Comment: yea its all contained in the one directory

Comment: Try to run qmake on your project.